# C# More simple way of converting an integer to a string in binary form without Convert.ToString method.?

Tags: c#, binary, integer, typeconverter

I have a code that turns an integer to its binary representation, but I was wondering if there is a more simple or "easier" way of doing so. I know that there is a built-in method in C# that does this for you automatically, but that is not what I want to use.

This version loops over each o the 32-bit positions while writing ones and zeros and uses TrimStart to remove leading zeroes.

For example, converting the integer 10 to its string representation in
binary as "1010".

```
static string IntToBinary(int n)
{
    char[] b = new char[32];
    int pos = 31;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 32) // Loops over each of the 32-bit positions while writing ones and zeros.
    {
        if ((n & (1 << i)) != 0)
        {
            b[pos] = '1';
        }
        else
        {
            b[pos] = '0';
        }
        pos--;
        i++;
    }
    return new string(b).TrimStart('0'); // TrimStart removes leading zeroes.
}

static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(IntToBinary(300));
}
```

Comment: **Why** don't you want to use `Convert.ToString` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use a nibble lookup table:

```
static string[] nibbles = {
    "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011",
    "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
    "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
    "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
};

public static string IntToBinary(int n)
{
    return 
        nibbles[(n >> 28) & 0xF] +
        nibbles[(n >> 24) & 0xF] +
        nibbles[(n >> 20) & 0xF] +
        nibbles[(n >> 16) & 0xF] +
        nibbles[(n >> 12) & 0xF] +
        nibbles[(n >>  8) & 0xF] +
        nibbles[(n >>  4) & 0xF] +
        nibbles[(n >>  0) & 0xF]
    .TrimStart('0');
}
```

Comment: This seems more complex yet simple when you understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple LINQ implementation:

```
static string IntToBinary(int n)
{
    return string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 32)
        .Select(i => (n & (1 << (31 - i))) != 0 ? '1' : '0')
        .SkipWhile(ch => ch == '0'));
}
```

Another one using `for` loop:

```
static string IntToBinary(int n)
{
    var chars = new char[32];
    int start = chars.Length;
    for (uint bits = (uint)n; bits != 0; bits >>= 1)
        chars[--start] = (char)('0' + (bits & 1));
    return new string(chars, start, chars.Length - start);
}
```